# Can you help me with a regex to match 2 different sections as a group from 1 string

Tags: regex

I need a bit of help with this. I’m expecting to get the matches:

- My Section
- Paragraph(b)

However, I seem to be including all the words in the middle rather than extracting them.

```regex
[\W]My Section[\W].*?\b(Paragraph[\s])\b
```

String:

```
“My Section” has the meaning specified in Paragraph 3(a) of this Annex.
```

Comment: Will `My  Section` portion always be within quotes?

Comment: Regex does not "extract" text... but most regex APIs allow you to view the contents of groups.

Comment: What do you mean you want to match “Paragraph(b)”? I don’t see that string inside the text you posted.

Answer (score 2):

I am making the assumption that the "My Section" portion will always be in quotes.

```
"(.*?)".*?\b(Paragraph\s?.*?)\s
```

This regex will have two matched groups, one for the quoted part, and one for the Paragraph location.

[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/4OfQKM/2/)

Comment: tx. it seems to be putting single quotes around the text, is that normal? Also the first text is always the text My Section not Another section. Is there a way to exclude the full match and just have the groups?

Comment: @user1898525 There is no way to exclude the entire match using only one match. You could use two regex statements if you want to match each seperately

Comment: So, using a coding language, I can extract the groups? I need to end up with 2 variables that say My Section and Paragraph (a). Also, why are there single quotes around the My Section text in the demo?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex matches the part before Paragraph with `[\W]My Section[\W].*?\b` and then captures in a group `Paragraph` followed by a whitespace and `3(a)` is not yet captured.

If the first text is always the text `My Section` and this format `Paragraph 3(a)` is always the same, you might update your regex use 2 capturing groups:

[`\W(My Section)\W.*?\b(Paragraph\s\d+\([^)]+\))`](https://regex101.com/r/6tNIbT/1/)

**Explanation**

- `\W` Match a non word character
- `(My Section)` Capture My Section in group 1
- `\W.*?\b` Match a non word character followed by any character zero or more times non greedy and a word boundary
- `(` Capturing group 2

  - `\s\d+` Match a whitespace character followed by one or more digits
  - `\([^)]+\)` First match `(`, then match not a `(` using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and then match `)`
- `)` Close capturing group

Instead of using `\W` at the beginning you could also use `“` and `”`

Answer (score 0):

The regex depends on language that you are using, if i get your question right, your regex should look like this

```
.*(My Section).*?(Paragraph\s?.*?)\s.*
```

Groups will be: 
1. whole-text
2. My Section
2. Paragraph 3(a)